# Is it possible to use gedit text editor with Java LibGDX?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, gedit, gedit-plugin

I have been using the gedit text editor for java, for some time now. But now i gonna try out LibGDX.
Is it possible to use the gedit text editor with LibGDX  or do i have to switch to Ecplise or IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: You can but developing is not just typing the code. What about debugging, publishing, handling dependencies... IMHO always go for the best accepted solution - and in this case it's Android studio. It's easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use whatever editor but it means that to launch all your Gradle Task to compile / build you will need to do so in command line.
I use Android Studio to do my games and it works well.
This also allow you to use the LibGDX formater plugin.

Comment: Thanks  you. Im gonna check out android studio :)

Comment: I ended up using Eclipse btw :)

Comment: Sounds good, What I like with Android Studio is that you can compile and run the simulators directly from within the IDE. Not sure this is possible with Eclipse. Maybe it is. Have a good game @robert!